# how can i send email in cakephp - to gmail account from localhost

Tags: php, email, cakephp

i'm begginer in this and i found with this problem...i wan to send email from my localhost  to a gmail account (this last can change for a hotmail), but first i want to prove for a gmail account. 
i had configure my email.php and it seems like this:

```
public $gmail = array(
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => 465,
        'username' => 'xxxxx@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'xxxx',
        'transport' => 'Smtp'
    );
```

and in my controller i have this

```
public function compras()
    {
        $Email = new CakeEmail();
        $Email->config('gmail');

        $this->loadModel('Soya');
        $this->paginate = array(
        'conditions' => array('Grupo.categoria' => 'Soya','Grupo.subcategoria' => 'Productor de Oleaginosas'),
        'limit' => 25
        );
        $this->set('soyas', $this->paginate('Soya'));
        $this->Email->to = 'xxxx@gmail.com';
        $this->Email->subject = 'Include your subject';
        $this->Email->from = 'xxxx@gmail.com';
        //$this->Email->template = 'template';  // file name template.ctp will be included in /views/elements/email/text/template.ctp
        $this->Email->delivery = 'smtp';
        if ($this->Email->send()
        )   {
        return true;
        } else {
        echo $this->Email->smtpError;
        }         
    }
```

but when i compile the errors appears

**Indirect modification of overloaded property SoyasController::$Email has no effect [APP/Controller/SoyasController.php, line 124]

Error: Call to a member function send() on a non-object **

please help!!!thanks a lot!!!

Comment: It looks to me like you are instantiating the CakeEmail class into the variable `$Email`, and then further down you are referring to it as `$this->Email->...` - `$this` refers to the current class (your controller), so in your case you should use `$Email->to` etc and not use `$this`

Comment: yeah it works but now i have this error: From is not specified.
Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.

Comment: i already found the solution thanks scrowler!! i bassed my solution on your answer!!... i was doing "$this->Email->from = 'xxxx@gmail.com';", but i found that is like this: "$Email->from(array('jmickyramirez@gmail.com' => 'My Site'));", in conclussion i have to delete '=' and put '(my code)'...thanks a lot scrowler!!..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public function compras()
        {
            $Email = new CakeEmail();
            $Email->config('gmail');

            $this->loadModel('Soya');
            $this->paginate = array(
            'conditions' => array('Grupo.categoria' => 'Soya','Grupo.subcategoria' => 'Productor de Oleaginosas'),
            'limit' => 25
            );
            $this->set(array('soyas', $this->paginate('Soya')));
            $Email->to('xxxx@gmail.com');
            $Email->subject('Include your subject');
            $Email->from('xxxx@gmail.com');


            if ($Email->send())   
            {
            return true;
            } else {
            echo $this->Email->smtpError;
            }         
        }
```